# failed to assign NativeSymbolInfo for Cdqrls when building R package

Tags: r, package

I am writing my package and get a warning when loading my package. I use the `Cdqrls` in some of my codes: `.Call(Cdqrls, x[, id1, drop=FALSE] * w,  w * z, epsilon)` and I also include a `lm.c` file in the `src` folder, which includes:

```
...
SEXP Cdqrls(SEXP x, SEXP y, SEXP tol)
{
    SEXP ans, ansnames;
    SEXP qr, coefficients, residuals, effects, pivot, qraux;
    int n, ny = 0, p, rank, nprotect = 4, pivoted = 0;
    double rtol = asReal(tol), *work;
...
```

However, when I install my package in R, the following warning message appear:

```
Warning message:
In FUN(1L[[1L]], ...) :
  failed to assign NativeSymbolInfo for Cdqrls since Cdqrls is already defined in the ‘My_Package_Name’ namespace
```

I Googled this warning message but got nothing... So I got two specific questions:

1. Have anyone experienced such warning before? Or could someone give me some suggestions on potential bugs/errors?
2. This warning won't influence my codes running for now, but it is pretty annoying. Is there a way to suppress this warning message when my end-users load the package? (Sorry I know this should be avoided, but just curious:)

**Update**

Just another note that may help debug the problem: I use

```
##'  @useDynLib My_Pkg_Name Cdqrls
##'  @keywords internal
```

for the function where `.Call(...)` is used.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it means that you have an object in your package namespace named `Cdqrls` *and* that's the name of the native symbol.

One way around it is to change your `.Call` to:

```
.Call("Cdqrls", x[,id1,drop=FALSE]*w, w*z, epsilon, PACKAGE="My_Package_Name")
```

Or you could change the native symbol or the other object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I changed that to my package name but it still shows the warning when loading... BTW, what is the native symbol?

Comment: @alittleboy: the "native symbol" is the name of the C/C++/Fortran function. Note that I didn't just add the `PACKAGE` argument, I changed `.Call(Cdqrls,...)` to `.Call("Cdqrls",...)`. Did you do that?

Comment: thanks! I changed to "Cdqrls" but it still shows the message. Currently I have the following files in my /src folder: `lm.c`, `lm.o` and `My_Pkg.so`, where `lm.c` is taken directly from base R. I also tried to change to `PACKAGE="base"` but still won't work...